# How do I update data frame variables with sapply results?

Tags: r

I have a number of Excel files that I will be loading into R after saving them as CSV files. Each Excel file several columns that are in currency format. I could adjust each column in Excel manually or with VBA, but I'd prefer to transform the variables in R. I'm using sapply to create a matrix with new values and formats for the columns.

I'm having trouble using the sapply results to change the variables. I'm trying to use `assign` with indexing in a `for` loop, but it's not working.

Here is a sample data frame and my code. Could you help me fix the last part? Also, would it be better to put the whole thing in a `for` loop and skip the `sapply`? I'm coming from Stata, and that's the way I know best, but I'm trying to learn the `apply` functions.

Thanks!

```
df <- data.frame(Price = c("$1.10", "$2.20", "($3.30)"),
    RetailPrice = c("$4.40", "$5.50", "($6.50)"), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

to.numeric <- function(var, data){

    data[,var] <- gsub("[$,]","", data[,var])
    data[,var] <- sub("^\\(","-", data[,var])
    data[,var] <- sub("\\)$","", data[,var])
    data[,var] <- as.numeric(data[,var])

    return(data[,var])
}

currency.vars <- c(
    "Price",
    "RetailPrice"
)

var.matrix <- sapply(currency.vars, to.numeric, data = df)

#Matrix looks as expected
View(var.matrix)                     
var.matrix[,1]
var.matrix[,"Price"]


for(i in 1:length(currency.vars)){

    #Doesn't work
    assign(paste("df[,", currency.vars[i], "]", sep = ""), 
        paste("var.matrix[,", i, "]", sep = ""))

}
```

Comment: If you want to replace `df` with `var.matrix` then, `df[] <- var.matrix`  Or is it necessary to use `assign` in a for loop?

Comment: This should work. Replace the code below the `#Doesn't work` with `df[, i] <- eval(parse(text=paste("var.matrix[,", i, "]", sep = "")))`

Comment: @akrun: I don't want to replace the whole data frame, since in the real data frame there are other non-currency columns. I think I could `cbind` var.matrix and delete the old variables, but that would change the order of the columns. I'm not clear on when `assign` is needed.

Comment: @dimitris_ps: Helpful, thanks. BrodieG's solution removes the need for this section of my code.

Comment: @KevinM If you have other columns as well in `df` Then `df[colnames(var.matrix)] <- var.matrix`

Comment: @KevinM I would consider that to much better than using `assign` and stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an equivalent version.  Notice how we don't need to pass the data frame as an argument to our function.  We are using `lapply` to pass the columns:

```
df[currency.vars] <- lapply(
  df[currency.vars], 
  function(x) as.numeric(sub("^\\(","-", gsub("[$,]|\\)$","", x)))
)
```

Produces:

```
  Price RetailPrice
1   1.1         4.4
2   2.2         5.5
3  -3.3        -6.5
```

There are two important points about using `lapply` with data frames:

1. We can directly `lapply` over a selected set of data frame columns
2. We can directly assign the `lapply` result back to the data frame columns

Both of these are possible because data frames are really lists of their columns.