# Can I nest apply functions in R?

Tags: r

I have a series of CSV files that I want to prepare to append together. My appended file will be large, so I'd like to convert some string variables to numeric and date formats in the individual files rather than the larger appended file.

With other software, I would have one `for` loop that opens the file and nested `for` loops that would iterate over certain groups of variables. For this project, I am attempting to use R and `apply` functions.

I have `mapply` and `lapply` functions that work independently. I'm now trying to figure out how to combine them. Can I nest them? (See below for the independent parts and the nesting.)

(This code references code in the answer to [How do I update data frame variables with sapply results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835543/how-do-i-update-data-frame-variables-with-sapply-results))

(Is it customary to provide an example CSV to give a reproducible example? Does R have built-in example CSVs?)

These work separately:

```
insert.division <- function(fileroot, divisionname){

    ext <- ".csv"
    file <- paste(fileroot, ext, sep = "")
    data <- read.csv(file, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    data$division <- divisionname
    write.csv(data, file = paste(fileroot, "_adj3", ext, sep = ""),
        row.names = FALSE)

}

files <- c(
    "file1",
    "file2",
    "file3",
    "file4",
    "file5"
)

divisions <- c(1:5)

#Open the files, insert division name, save new versions
mapply(insert.division, fileroot = files, divisionname = divisions)

#Change currency variables from string to numeric
currency.vars <- c(
    "Price",
    "RetailPrice"
)

df[currency.vars] <- lapply(
    df[currency.vars], 
    function(x) as.numeric(sub("^\\(","-", gsub("[$,]|\\)$","", x)))
)
```

Combined version:

```
file.prep <- function(fileroot, divisionname, currency.vars){

    ext <- ".csv"
    file <- paste(fileroot, ext, sep = "")
    data <- read.csv(file, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    data$division <- divisionname

    df[currency.vars] <- lapply(
    df[currency.vars], 
    function(x) as.numeric(sub("^\\(","-", gsub("[$,]|\\)$","", x)))
    )

    write.csv(data, file = paste(fileroot, "_adj", ext, sep = ""),
        row.names = FALSE)

}

#Open the files, insert division name, change the currency variables,
    #save new versions
mapply(file.prep, fileroot = files, divisionname = divisions,
    currency.vars = df[currency.vars])
```

Comment: What's your intended output here? It seems like you just want to add a loop inside your `insert.division` function? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Thomas: I want to have one outer loop that opens each file and does some things to it. I want to have inner loops that process certain groups of variables. The insert division would be one of several tasks.

Comment: The general question is how to use `apply` functions to replace nested `for` loops.

Comment: All you're currently showing us, though, is reading and saving a bunch of files, but you don't actually do anything to them. Where does the manipulation part go? And why can't you just put that in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you're writing it back to file after changing the data, but here's an example of how I might approach the problem.

```
## Set up three csv files
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(
    w = paste0("($", sample(1500, 30) / 100, ")"),
    x = Sys.Date() + 0:29,
    y = sample(letters, 30, TRUE),
    z = paste0("($", sample(1500, 30) / 100, ")")
)
fnames <- paste0("file", 1:3, ".csv")
Map(write.csv, split(DF, c(1, 10, 20)), fnames, row.names = FALSE)
```

Using your `file.prep()` function, you could adjust it a little and do

```
file.prep <- function(fileroot, divname, vars) {
    ext <- ".csv"
    file <- paste0(fileroot, ext)
    data <- read.csv(file, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    data$division <- divname
    data[vars] <- lapply(data[vars], function(x) {
            type.convert(gsub("[()$]", "", x))
        })
    write.csv(data, row.names = FALSE, file = paste0(fileroot, "_adj", ext))
}

divname <- 1:3
fnames <- paste0("file", divname)

Map(file.prep, fnames, divname, MoreArgs = list(vars = c("w", "z")))
```

Comment: It's good to know that I can put `lapply` statements inside a function that I am already calling with `lapply`. Writing the separate CSVs was in case it would take too much memory to hold all of the data frames individually as well as the final appended one, but it seems to be unnecessary. Also, that's how it would be done in Stata, which I'm used to using.